# GitHub collaborators cannot download private repo via NPM package

Tags: git, github, ssh, npm, package

I have a private repository as a dependency in an NPM `package.json`.

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
  "private-repo": "git+ssh://git@github.com/shennan/private-repo.git"
}
```

I have an SSH key linked with my GitHub account, and all works well when I `npm install` on the command line.

The problem is that I can't get any of the other collaborators' `npm install` working. They are set as collaborators of the `private-repo` repository, and I believe they have SSH linked via Github for Windows. They *can* easily clone the `private-repo` via the Github for Windows application, but they cannot install it via the `npm install` command on the command line.

A couple of points:

- they **do** have access to the `git` command on the command line
- they **don't** have access to the `ssh-keygen` command on the command line
- they **do** have a github public/private key in `C:\Users\<user>\.ssh`
- they **cannot** clone the `private-repo` using the Git Bash application
- they **can** clone the `private-repo` using Github for Windows GUI
- the error they get is an SSH permission denied

I have tried adding the Git binary to their path, which is something like:

`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<guid>\cmd`

Even on restarting the command prompt, they still cannot `npm install` the private repo successfully.

What haven't I tried? Is this even possible with Windows + NPM + Git?